# Need to read values from an excel using gcloud or shell scripting

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I run the gcloud command below for project "A"

"gcloud alpha projects update --update-labels env=dev,name=projectA"

this will update the labels for one project. However I am not able to figure out how to read the same values from an excel file and then update the labels through shell scripting/gcloud command

Comment: You can try to save your excel file as `Text (tab delimited) (*.txt)`, after that you'll be able to use [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) and [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) to run `gcloud` command with required arguments by searching through the text file and using results as arguments.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Apologie, didn't understood. Are you saying i should try like this: gcloud alpha projects update --update-labels env=dev,name=projectA | grep "fileA"

Comment: No, it could be something like  `cat labels.txt | grep ... | awk ... | xargs gcloud alpha projects update --update-labels env=$2,name=projectA`